# python gcc and setuptools error during lxml installation

Tags: python, linux, gcc, centos, lxml

I am trying to install LXML on centos (amazon linux AMI).

I have installed the following prereqs:

```
sudo yum install libxml2-devel libxslt-devel
sudo yum install zlib-devel
sudo pip install setuptools
sudo yum install python-devel
```

I then install lxml with:

```
sudo pip install lxml
```

I get the following gcc error:

> creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml
>       gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o
>   build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w
>       {standard input}: Assembler messages:
>       {standard input}:593226: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.lc1'
>       gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
>       Please submit a full bug report,
>       with preprocessed source if appropriate.
>       See http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla for instructions.
>       Compile failed: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 4
>       creating tmp
>       cc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /tmp/xmlXPathInit0HczkK.c -o tmp/xmlXPathInit0HczkK.o
>       cc tmp/xmlXPathInit0HczkK.o -L/usr/lib64 -lxml2 -o a.out
>       error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 4
>
> ```
> ----------------------------------------
> ```
>
> Command "/usr/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-TmaL5z/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**,
>   'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-OD8Xpx-record/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-TmaL5z/lxml

My gcc version is:
gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)

My python version is:
Python 2.7.12

How can I get past this error to install LXML ?

Answer (score 0):

I installed those I mentioned above:

```
sudo yum install libxml2-devel libxslt-devel
sudo yum install zlib-devel
sudo pip install setuptools
sudo yum install python-devel
```

And these two did the trick:

```
sudo yum install glibc-devel glibc-headers
Sudo yum groupinstall "Development tools”



sudo pip install lxml
```